# Necessary condition for the intersection of two submanifolds to be a submanifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold. How could I prove that for arbitrary submanifolds $M$, $N$ of dimension $n-m$,$n-k$, if $\forall x\in M\cap N$:
$\dim( T_xM\cap T_xN) = n-m-k$ then $M\cap N$ is a submanifold?? This is easy when $N$, $M$ are preimages of regular values of some smooth function but what if they are not?

Comment: Hint: Being manifold is a local property and **locally** every manifold is preimage  of regular values of smooth function.

Comment: You mean to use some projection function for the submanifold? this will only be from a chart however.. Can you please write an answer I am confused?